# Qt 5.15.2 Windows 11 qmake stuck

Tags: qt, qmake

I'm trying to build a newly created empty project on my pc, but the build stucks with this command ->

```
11:55:02: Starting: "C:\Qt\5.15.2\mingw81_64\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Progetti\untitled\untitled.pro -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug".
```

After a while it says ->

```
Info: creating stash file C:\Progetti\untitled\build\Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit\Debug\.qmake.stash
```

If i let it going, the entire output is

```
12:54:54: Running steps for project untitled...
12:54:54: Starting: "C:\Qt\5.15.2\mingw81_64\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Progetti\untitled\untitled.pro -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
Info: creating stash file
C:\Progetti\untitled\build\Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit\Debug\.qmake.stash
13:02:56: The process "C:\Qt\5.15.2\mingw81_64\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
13:02:56: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" -f C:/Progetti/untitled/build/Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit/Debug/Makefile qmake_all
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for 'qmake_all'.
13:02:56: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
13:02:56: Elapsed time: 08:01.
```

I've also tried to reinstall Qt without success.
Why is this happening? It worked until a few days ago, I can't understand what's going on.

Comment: We really need more information to solve this issue. F.ex use Task Manger and/or procmon to check why your system is so busy. Bad/failing/slow/full hard drive? Did you update something? ...

Comment: @m7913d my pc is on ssd and takes 5 seconds to boot, it is really fast, however, when I run qmake the whole pc slows down, even if the cpu remains at 10% max. The funny thing is that it worked like a charm until a few weeks ago. From what I remember the only thing I've updated is Windows 11 -> KB5023706(I tried to rollback the last update but still hangs)

Comment: Your best option is to monitor what your pc is actually doing, using Task Manager, Resource Manager, procmon, ... Probably it is IO related. procmon may give you detailed information in that case. Without this information, it's unlikely you will receive a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Can't post a direct comment so I'll post an answer: In my experience, qmake slowness is often caused by it chasing down headers to use as dependencies. This usually takes seconds and not minutes though and shouldn't be an issue with empty projects. Try looking at the generated files such as Makefile.Release to check whether the output is unusual.

[Procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) is also very helpful in these cases - do a capture, then filter for qmake.exe and see where it's looking for files. Could be that somehow it's iterating over a slow network share or something like that.